# Metapost: path definition

Tags: paths, metapost

I am a newbie of metapost. Please forgive my question if it is too simple.

1. Can we define a path for two parallel lines？ As daleif explained below, the answer is no since it is not a connected entity.
2. Can we define a path for a connected entity that cannot be drawn in `one stroke`? For example, the picture below. Now I can't build one path for it.

[image]

I regard path as a block (including many items) and you can do action on the path thus working on all the items in the path. For example, for the above image, if it can be defined as a path `grid`, we can define grid linetype for all lines by `draw grid dashed dashpattern(on 1bp off 2bp on 10bp off 2bp);`. We can also do transformation on path.

Comment: A path is a connected entity. Two parallel lines are probably either a function or made a the type `picture` (this is an entiry that can have many things)

Comment: Can you be a but more specific about what you are trying to do?  What sort of "actions" do you want to do to the path?  And what do you mean by "But the path example from tutorial always has intersection points" ?  which example? from which tutorial?

Comment: @ Thruston, I updated the post. As to tutorial, there are a lot, e.g., mpman.pdf, or this: http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html

Comment: You perhaps are interested in a `picture` object rather than a `path`. Also pictures can be manipulated.

Comment: I’m familiar with the various tutorials, but I wondered which one you were referring to in the sentence you have now deleted.

Comment: You *can* define a path for that shape, if you don’t mind repeating a segment. But there is no real need to do this. Just draw the segments separately. If you don’t want to repeat the `dashpattern` part then just learn how to use `drawoptions`.

Comment: @Thruston, thank you. Learn the `drawoptions`. Glad to know it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how to use a `picture` variable as @egreg suggests:

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

z1 = -z5 = 70 right;
z3 = 70 up;
z2 = whatever[z1,z3]; z2 = whatever * (z3-z1) rotated 90;
z4 = whatever[z3,z5]; z4 = whatever * (z5-z3) rotated 90;

picture truss;
truss = image(
draw z1--z3--z5--cycle;
draw origin -- z2;
draw origin -- z3;
draw origin -- z4;
);

draw truss slanted .4 shifted 84 up dashed withdots scaled 1/2 withcolor red;
draw truss dashed dashpattern(on 4 off 2 on 1/2 off 2);

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Wonderful! It is more like a block I said in my post. Thank you for teaching how to use `picture`.